# Using regex in find/replace

Tags: replace, find, sublimetext3

I am working on a nodejs/express project which have a deprecated way of accessing request parameters :

`req.param('parameter')` instead of the valid `req.params.parameter`.

There is a lot of occurence in the project and I need to fix it. My question is how can I do to find the string's start `"req.param('"` until the string's end `"')"`, extract `parameter` from the result, and then replace to have `req.params.parameter` ?

```
find:
req.param('str')
replace:
req.params.str
```

NOTE :
 Following the validated answer, to reverse this replace pattern, use :

```
(req\.params\.)([^; \n]+)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the find and replace box (`ctrl+h`) you can insert as the search regex:

```
(req\.param)\('([^']+)'\)
```

and replace it with

```
$1.$2
```

Explanation:
The first group `(req\.param)` is accessed via `$1` and you could also change it to match more prefixes. Afterwards open a paren and a string. In the second group `([^']+)` everything except a string closing char is matched. And afterwards the string and the paren is closed.

Comment: Just to be certain: you did check RegEx in the search&replace dialog?